# south migration: DatabaseOperations has not attribute 'shorten_name'

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south, data-migration

I have a model  which I managed to migrate on two different computers without a problem. However on my server I'm getting the following error:

> Error in migration: some_app:0002_auto__some_migration
>
> AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object **has no attribute 'shorten_name'**

Inspecting the migration file I see a line:

```
    m2m_table_name = db.shorten_name(u'some_app_some_class_some_attribute')
```

which could be the culprit.  (there are a few lines which use this `shorten_name`.  I'm not sure how to solve this.

The virtual environment on my server has South 0.7.6, Django 1.5 (and a Postgis enabled postgres)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error originates from a version conflict. You migration might have been created with a later version of South (probably in your dev environment) and your production version runs on a earlier version.

Compare the version numbers of the South installations with

```
pip freeze
```

and see which South version is listed in both environments.